# SD card path not found of device while testing Amazon InappPurchase

Tags: in-app-purchase

I am testing my Amazon Inapp Purchases for which i need to push a json file into the Android device mnt/sdcard path.But my phone is not showing such path.So i have created one and inserted the file into that.But still when i run my application the error log says that

The json file does not found.

Can any one tell me how i can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Start android monitor(DDMS), connect the device and go to file explorer tab. You will see "sdcard" folder in that. Push the json file to this folder